# Calling setVolumeControlStream from a Service

Tags: android, android-service, android-audiomanager

I need to call `setVolumeControlStream` from a service that plays some sound via `STREAM_SYSTEM`.
Obviously in an Activity that is no problem, but how can I do this with a service?

Answer (score 3):

From the looks of it, this isn't possible the way you are trying to do it.

As said in the [android reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setVolumeControlStream%28int%29)

> The suggested audio stream will be tied to the window of this Activity

Hence with a service that has no activity, there is no window to tie the audio stream to.

However, It looks like you should be able to receive media key events (including volume keys) from a broadcaster as shown [here](http://developer.android.com/training/managing-audio/volume-playback.html) which would allow you to change your service volume without an activity being visible.

Comment: I've looked at this solution and it doesn't seem to work: there is no way to use broadcast receivers to receive volume keys events. On the link you posted, android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON is used for playback buttons, like play/pause, next, previous, etc... But no volume buttons.

Comment: My mistake then, I guess this isn't possible from a service. The reason seemingly is therefore to stop apps capturing the volume events and interfering with the ability of the user to change ringer volume/system volume. Is there any reason why you cannot use STREAM_MUSIC?

Comment: In my case, it's because I would like to mute other apps while my app plays music. As all other apps use STREAM_MUSIC, the solution I found was to mute STREAM_MUSIC and use another stream.

Comment: Some music apps such as MortPlayer and Audible allow you to control the media volume even when the Activity is not active. There must be another solution somehow...

Answer (score 2):

I think this library can provide you what you need:

http://code.google.com/p/media-volume-control/

Comment: It is not possible if the library either (although it does look nice).